# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

> EDIT: This is not a duplicate, I have fixed the NullPointerException and its no longer duplicate. Please unflag this as duplicate.
>
> Thanks to @Fondesa, I had already fixed the NullPointerException. I have read the other Question @Tunaki linked it to, it was helpful. But it didn't solve my problem completely.

I'm trying to have a listfragment in my main activity, but there's the android.view.InflateException. Any help would be very deeply appreciated. I've been stuck at this for a day now.

This is the error log.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.idiots.redundant.digiteyes_beacon, PID: 3626
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.idiots.redundant.digiteyes_beacon/com.idiots.redundant.digiteyes_beacon.Exxplore}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
                                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                     at com.idiots.redundant.digiteyes_beacon.Exxplore.onCreate(Exxplore.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6072)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1046)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                     at com.idiots.redundant.digiteyes_beacon.Exxplore.onCreate(Exxplore.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6072) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Exxplore.java:148 `setContentView(R.layout.product_list);`
The main activity XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    />
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/authenticationfragment"
    android:name="com.idiots.redundant.digiteyes_beacon.authentication"
    />

<fragment
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/productlistfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.idiots.redundant.digiteyes_beacon.ADlister"
    />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/ctafragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.idiots.redundant.digiteyes_beacon.fragCTA"
    />
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    tools:context="com.idiots.redundant.digiteyes_beacon.Exxplore">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


        <ListView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/prodlistview"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The fragment class that is failing.

```
public class ADlister extends ListFragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private fragCTA.OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
ListView listView;
ArrayList <Result> results;
FragmentListAdapter adapter;

public ADlister() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adlister, container, false);
    listView =(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.prodlistview_fragement);
    Exxplore exxplore= (Exxplore) getActivity();
    results=exxplore.getlist();
    if(results!=null&&results.size()!=0)
        lister();
    return view;
}
void lister(){
    int count=results.size();
    String produrls[]=new String[count];
    String prodname[]=new String[count];
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        prodname[i]=results.get(i).getProduct_title();
        produrls[i]=results.get(i).getProduct_url();
    }
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    assert listView != null;
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    Exxplore exxplore= (Exxplore) getActivity();
    results=exxplore.getlist();

    lister();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}
```

The function `exxplore.getlist()` returns an array list of type Result.

Comment: Did you tried changing "android:name" in fragment tag to "class" ?

Comment: @sunilsunny Yes. Still didn't work.

Comment: @Tunaki Please unflag, I figured out the solution and i would like to answer it myself.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to solve this error **at com.idiots.redundant.digiteyes_beacon.ADlister.lister(ADlister.java:64)**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
at com.idiots.redundant.digiteyes_beacon.ADlister.lister(ADlister.java:64)
at com.idiots.redundant.digiteyes_beacon.ADlister.onCreateView(ADlister.java:50)
```

Comment: Fixed that. Still the same error. I have made some edits in the question could you please check again?

Comment: I could not found where you initialize your adapter. check if it is null or what. and also check at here. **com.idiots.redundant.digiteyes_beacon.ADlister.onCreateView(ADlister.java:50)**

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

After your edit, you have to check for null list in `onCreateView()`:

```
if(results != null && results.size()!=0)
    lister();
```

Comment: I fixed that. Please check my edit.

Comment: @Fondesa what is meaning of  for(int i=0;i<count;i++){} if count is 0 then it will break it self  and does not go inside then how it is possible ?

Comment: Thank You.
But other errors still remain. Please check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should add in a null check for results -

```
results = exxplore.getlist();
if (results != null && results.size() != 0)
    lister();
return view;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Exxplore exxplore= (Exxplore) getActivity();
```

Its not ideal way to get `Activity` Instance inside your `onCreateView()` method. Please use `onAttach(Activity mActivity)` method to get your activity Instance.

Comment: onAttach(android.app.Activity) deprecated it says

Comment: yes, you should try onAttach(Context mContext) instead..

Comment: Yeah did that. Thank You.
Although the isn't the exact issue.